# Javascript to Java communication via Socket programming

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, websocket

I am new to Javascript.I want to establish communication between java & javascript.I was planning to use Socket programming for it.But I dont know whether it can be done or not using **websocket in javascript & server socket in java** ?While googling I saw **JAVASOCKETBRIDGE**.But  I  dont know how to do it.Can anyone provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution does not use websocket, but it does the job well (decorrelate the view- javascript- to the controller - java): [DWR - Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

After there are plenty of other solutions for that kind of problem, like using [GWT - Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuide.html).